# escape a whole array of arguments for use in sh-like shells with a standard tool

Tags: linux, bash, shell, escaping, sh

I'm looking for a standard tool capable of taking all of its arguments and turning it into a single string suitable for use as multiple arguments in an automatically generated bash/sh/zsh script. Such a command is extremely useful in various disciplines of script-fu. An example of its usage:

```
% shsafe 'A big \nasty string '\'' $HOME $PATH' 'another string \\'
'A big \nasty string '\'' $HOME $PATH' 'another string \\'
```

Using it in another script:

```
% sshc host rm 'file/with spaces and $special chars'
```

where `sshc` contains

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: sshc host command [arg ...]
# Escapes its arguments so that the command may contain special 
# characters. Assumes the remote shell is sh-like.
host=$1
shift
exec ssh "$host" "$(shsafe "$@")"
```

Another example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run multiple commands in a single sudo session. The arguments of 
# this script are passed as arguments to the first command. Useful if 
# you don't want to have to type the password for both commands and 
# the first one takes a while to run.
sudo bash -c "pacman -Syu $(shsafe "$@") && find /etc -name '*.pacnew'"
```

I couldn't find a suitable solution to this problem in the pre-existing commands, so I made up my own, called `shsafe`. It uses the fact that  single quotes, `''`, turn off absolutely all shell expansion, except for `'` itself.

`shsafe`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import *

n = len(argv)
if n == 1:
    exit(0)

i = 1
while True:
    stdout.write("'" + argv[i].replace("'", "'\\''") + "'")
    i += 1
    if i == n:
        break
    stdout.write(' ')

stdout.write('\n')
```

Is there any standard tool capable of doing this to its arguments?

Note that the printf command with a format string consisting of just the %q formatter is not good enough for this, because it won't keep multiple arguments separated:

```
% printf %q arg1 arg2
arg1arg2
```

Comment: `printf "%q " arg1 arg2` ? `printf "%q" "arg1 arg2"` ?

Comment: I thought of that. Even with the space, arg1 and arg2 will be treated as the same argument, separated by a space. `printf '$'\''%q'\'' ' arg1 arg2` does work, though. It's extremely error prone, though, having to type that out every time. I don't consider that a good enough solution because of that, even if it did only use standard tools.

Comment: Do you mean `$'\'%q\' '` ? How do you want the string to look when it is printed?

Comment: isn't `xargs` solution to your problem?

Comment: No, that's something different, @nopasara. `man xargs` to learn what it does.

Answer (score 1):

I did eventually figure out a decent way of doing this:

```
% printf "$'%q' " 'crazy string \ $HOME' 'another\ string'
$'crazy\ string\ \\\ \$HOME' $'another\\\ string'
```

It's a little error prone what with the quotes everywhere, so it's not ideal, IMO, but it's a solid solution that should work anywhere. If it's being used a lot, you could always turn it into a shell function:

```
shsafe () {
    printf "$'%q' " "$@"
}
```

Comment: POSIX doesn't require either `$'...'` or `%q` to be supported.